# How to stop my email messages being marked as read when a POP client downloads them?

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap, pop3

I access my email in two ways from Thunderbird. I have one POP account and one IMAP. The problem is that this makes messages coming to through IMAP *marked as read* before I actually read them on any account. This is causing a severe problem as I may miss some emails.

The email server is Exchange.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

POP is working as designed, here.  If you access a mailbox via the Post Office Protocol, you are expected to be *transferring it **off** the server* to storage of your own.  (RFCs 1081 and 1939 both make this point explicit in their introductions.)  From the server's point of view a message that has been `RETR`ieved but not yet `DELE`ted is indeed "read" by the POP client.

If you are using the Post Office Protocol to keep mail on the server indefinitely, then you are in fact *ab*using the protocol.  POP has never required that maildrops hold mail indefinitely.  Indeed, RFC 1939 § 8 is clear about the fact that servers are quite free to outright *delete* messages that you've retrieved but not deleted yourself, let alone simply mark them as read.  The Post Office Protocol is, as the name suggests, a protocol where mail is held at a "post office" *drop point*, from which you collect it *and take it away* whenever your MUA is connected to the network.

So your question is essentially unanswerable.  You are asking how to make POP *not* work as designed.  Of course, this is another case of [picking the unsuitable tool for job and then asking how to modify the tool so that it works](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html).  If you want a protocol that's designed around the paradigm of having a remote mailbox maintained on a mail server (rather than POP's last-leg-of-the-store-and-forward-chain paradigm) which is accessed by multiple client MUAs, then use IMAP.  It's that simple.

Comment: Yes. If theres better tool existing theres no need to change it to worse.

Comment: A semi-fix to this is to not completely download the message on POP3. Retrieve a portion or just headers, and it won't be marked as read. See my Q&A http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/149507/why-is-my-email-being-marked-as-read/149508#149508